# Set the GUID for the value at textbox FormView aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, formview

I've created FormView let user enter the data to save into database. And i need to disable one of the textbox and automatic set the GUID to the textbox. how can i do that?

```
  <InsertItemTemplate>
  RouteGUID:
  <asp:TextBox ID="RouteGUIDTextBox" runat="server" 
  Text='<%# Bind("RouteGUID") %>' Enabled="False" />
   <br />
```

Comment: what problem you are getting..

Comment: @MayankPathak i do want to know how to automatic fill the value of textbox with GUID w/o user enter any value.

Comment: are you taking input of GUID in the same textbox, and want to display that value after value gets saved in DB, right.. ?

Comment: @MayankPathak i want GUID automatic filled in the textbox when user open the page.

Comment: @MayankPathak thanks. i got the idea.

Comment: welcome, and let me know.. any other issues you face...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should Bind the `FormView` control on `Page_Load`..or should call the `Formview.DataBind()` method on `page_load`...as i can't see your full code, so said this as an assumption.